# How does this code exactly work in C Language? (A Beginner Question)

Tags: c

This code is for printing the inverse half pyramid:

```
* * * 
* * 
*
```

---

```
#include<stdio.h>
int main() {
    int i, j, rows;
    printf("Enter number of rows: ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);
    for (i=rows; i>=1; --i) 
    {
        for (j=1; j<=i; ++j)
        { 
            printf("* ");
        }
        printf("\n");
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

Let's say if I enter rows = 5, then "i" will initialize its value as 5, check if it's greater than 1,
then we go to the 2nd for loop, where j has the initial value of 1, and then check if it's less than the value of "i= 5", which it IS, then after that, how will the second loop run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The first `for` loop is to decrement from 5 (`rows` variable) to 1 (since it is inverted half pyramid).

The second/inner `for` loop (loop `j`) is to print the `*` character `i` times (`i` is set in outer `for` loop).

Once the inner `for` loop exits, a new line is printed (`\n`) and `i` is decremented and the inner loop runs again for the new value of `i`.

Comment: Okay, so basically what it'll do is, it will start printing directly from the 5th row, and then get to the top, right?

Answer (score 0):

```
* * * *
* * *
* *
*
```

The above pattern contains `N` rows and each row contains `N-i + 1` columns (where `i` is the current row number). Considering this let us write a step by step descriptive logic to print inverted right triangle star pattern.

1. Input number of rows to print from user. Store it in a variable say `rows`.
2. To iterate through rows run an outer loop from 1 to `rows`. The loop structure should look like `for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)`.
3. To iterate through columns run an inner loop from `i` to `rows`. The loop structure should look like `for(j=i; j<=rows; j++)`. Inside this loop print star.

   Note: Instead of iterating from `i` to `rows` you can also iterate from 1 to `rows - i + 1`.
4. After printing all columns of a row, move to next line i.e. print new line.

Good explanation taken from https://codeforwin.org/2015/07/inverted-right-triangle-star-pattern-program-in-c.html

```
/**
 * Reverse right triangle star pattern program in C
 */

#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i, j, rows;

    /* Input number of rows from user */
    printf("Enter number of rows : ");
    scanf("%d", &rows);

    /* Iterate through rows */
    for(i=1; i<=rows; i++)
    {
        /* Iterate through columns */
        for(j=i; j<=rows; j++)
        {
            printf("* ");
        }

        /* Move to the next line */
        printf("\n");
    }

    return 0;
}
```